# How is $\frac d {dx} [u(x)\cdot y ]=q(x) \cdot u(x)$ a separable differential equation?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

The text I am reading makes reference the separable differential equation $\frac d {dx} [u(x)\cdot y ]=q(x) \cdot u(x)$, when reading about how to solve first order differential equations. I have learnt that a seperable equation is an equation of the form $y'=f(x) \cdot g(x)$- how is $\frac d {dx} [u(x)\cdot y ]=q(x) \cdot u(x)$ of this form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put $v(x) = u(x)y$, and you got a separable differential equation. Note that if $y$ is a function of $x$, then $v$ is also a function of $x$ and it fits the definition of $v' = q(x)u(x)$ hence is separable.

Comment: What you’ve written doesn’t make sense. How does it make sense to write $v(y)$?

Comment: @tedshifrin should it be $v(x)$ instead?

Comment: If we tacitly are treating $y$ as an unknown function of $x$, yes.